# Python 2.7 trying to make this book text lowercase

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my code so far, the idea is to make all words lowercase, count the unique words (ones that are not repeated) as well as count the number of times "uncle" is typed in the book.

```
word_cnt = 0

book = open("shunned_house.txt")
lower = book.lower()

for line in lower:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
    word_cnt += 1

print word_cnt
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried many different variations of this problem and keep getting stuck right here. In terms of words counted in this document its around 10700 or so. I especially have trouble setting the python code up to tackle the problem.

Comment: use a `Counter` for counting stuff. and `lower = book.lower()` probably won't work. `book` is a file, not a string. also, you may need to remove punctuations

Comment: and your indentation is wrong

Comment: Ok I'll look into that, thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you want:

```
with open('shunned_house.txt') as f:
    book = f.read().lower()

words = book.split()

print len(set(words))
print book.count('uncle')
```

Comment: What a precise one ! This is how we should deal with noobs . Good job

Comment: wow. I am definitely new at this and I appreciate your help. any suggestions  for resources to learn?

Comment: so "set" counts unique items and what does "len" do? the rest of it I understand in terms of reading it, just can't write it on my own yet...

Comment: ok so "len" gives me total count and "set" counts unique values within the "len" pretty neat stuff if you ask me.

Comment: Well it looks like you figured it out yourself while I was asleep, but in mathematics, [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) are unique collections of objects. In Python, the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) class models this behavior. It is great for finding unique items, but it can also be used for so much more. I recommend that you read about it for the future. [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) (short for length) returns how many items are in an object. So `len(set())` returns how many unique items are in an object.